# Get a list of lines from a file

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

I have a huge file (millions of lines). I want to get a random sample from it, I've generated a list of unique random numbers and now I want to get all the lines whose line number would match my random numbers generated.

Sorting the random numbers is not a problem, so I was thinking I can take the difference between consecutive numbers and just jump the difference with the cursor in the file.

I think I should use `sed` or `awk`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's an easy way to read random line from a file in Unix command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448005/whats-an-easy-way-to-read-random-line-from-a-file-in-unix-command-line)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you directly use `shuf` to get random lines:

```
shuf -n NUMBER_OF_LINES file
```

#### Example

```
$ seq 100 >a   # the file "a" contains number 1 to 100, each one in a line

$ shuf -n 4 a
54
46
30
53

$ shuf -n 4 a
50
37
63
21
```

---

### Update

> Can I somehow store the number of lines shuf chose? –  Pio

As I did in [How to efficiently get 10% of random lines out of the large file in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21755062/1983854), you can do something like this:

```
shuf -i 1-1000 -n 5 > rand_numbers # store the list of numbers
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]; next} {if (FNR in a) print}' list_of_numbers a #print those lines
```

Comment: Wow... I did not know of this :). Can I somehow store the number of lines shuf chose?

Comment: In a bash script if I store the `wc -l filename > max`, then how do I get only the first element of `wc -l` not the filename as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` and `shuf`:

```
shuf file.txt > shuf.txt
awk '!a[$0]++' shuf.txt > uniqed.txt
```

This `awk` is best tool for removing duplicates.